# SQL mass string manipulation

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm working with an oracle DB and need to manipulate a string column within it. The column contains multiple email addresses in this format:

jgooooll@gmail.com;dhookep@gmail.com;amoore@outlook.com

What I want to do is take out anything that does **not** have '@gmail.com' at the end (in this example amoore@outlook.com would be removed) however amoore@outlook.com may be the first email in the next row of the column so in this way there is no real fixed format, the only format being that each address is seperated by a semi-colon.

Is there anyway of implementing this through one command to run through every row in the column and remove anything thats not @gmail.com?  I'm not really sure if this kind of processing is possible in SQL. Just looking for your thoughts!!

Thanks a lot you guys. Look forward to hearing from you!

Comment: This is rather hard to do in most databases, because they are not optimized for string access.  You either need support for full regular expressions or to write your own function.  By the way, storing such a list in a field is a bad idea, for exactly this reason.  There should be a separate table of emails, with one email per row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applicable to Oracle 11g (11.2) onward only. Because `listagg` function is supported only in 11.2 onward. If you are using 10.1 onward up to 11.1, you can write your own string aggregate function or take [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402) one.

```
with T1 as (
  select 1 id, 'jhd@jk.com;jgooooll@gmail.com;dhookep@gmail.com;amoore@outlook.com' emails from dual union all
  select 2 id, 'jhd@jk.com;jgooooll@gmail.com;dhookep@gmail.com;amoore@outlook.com' emails from dual 
) 

select id
     , listagg(email, ';') within group(order by id) emails
  from (select id 
             , regexp_substr(emails,'[^;]+', 1, rn) email 
          from t1 
         cross join (select rownum rn
                       from(select max (regexp_count(emails, '[^;]+')) ml
                              from t1
                            )
                           connect by level <= ml      
                      )
         )                             
where email like '%@gmail.com%'
group by id

Id               Emails 
--------------------------------------
1     dhookep@gmail.com;jgooooll@gmail.com 
2     dhookep@gmail.com;jgooooll@gmail.com
```

Here is a [**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d4ed/1)

Comment: Nicholas I'm kind of confused with some of this. I realise that this is a perfect piece of sql but im having trouble wrapping my head around it. Would you mind if I posted an answer with my exact code, as I cannot get it to work? maybe you will see something?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is actually for SQL Server, as that is what I know. That being said, perhaps having an example of how to do it in one system will give you an idea of how to do it in yours. Or maybe there is a way to convert the code into the same type of thing in Oracle.

First, the thought process: In SQL Server combining the `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` functionality allows you to make a comma separated list. I'm adding a `WHERE Split.SplitValue LIKE ...` clause into this to filter it to only gmail addresses. I'm cross applying this whole thing to the main table, and that turns it into a filtered email list. You could then further filter the main table to run this on a more targeted set of rows.

Second, the SQL Server implementation:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM @Table Base
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT
        STUFF(
            (SELECT
                ';' + Split.SplitValue AS [text()]
            FROM dbo.fUtility_Split(Base.Emails, ';') Split
            WHERE Split.SplitValue LIKE '%@gmail.com'
            FOR XML PATH (''))
        , 1, 1, '') Emails
) FilteredEmails
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this answer requires you have some sort of function to split a string column based on a separator value. If you don't have that already, then google for it. There are tons of examples.